# A Java MySQL INSERT(using PreparedStatement)

Tags: java, mysql

I have a small question to you guys.

I tryed to add user to database.

User have field like: id, name, surname etc.

Method

```
public static String insertUsertoDatabase(Connection con, User userToAdd)
```

doing something like this

```
 // the mysql insert statement
        String query = " insert into User (id,log,pass)"
                + " values (?, ?, ?)";

        // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setInt(1, 1);
        preparedStmt.setString(2, "h");
        preparedStmt.setString(3, "l");
```

setUser method

```
    public String setUser(User userToBase) {
    return insertUsertoDatabase(con, userToBase);
}
```

and main.java

```
User us1 = new User("9", "h", "l");
db.setUser(us1); //insert to database User u1
```

How can I put values from User constructor to preparedStmt ?

I have a constructor like that:

```
public class User(id, login, pass) {
      this.id = id;
      etc.
```

}

but i want to know how can I send data from constructor

```
User us1 = new User("9", "h", "l");
```

to my method

```
public static String insertUsertoDatabase(Connection con, User userToAdd)



    preparedStmt.setInt(1, 9);           <-------------    from User constructor
    preparedStmt.setString(2, "h");
    preparedStmt.setString(3, "l");
```

Comment: Close that PreparedStatement when you're done with it. Not closing it can leak resources.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like that:

```
// TODO: use meaningful names
private String pim;
private String pam;
private String poom;

public User(String pim, String pam, String poom) {
    this.pim = pim;
    this.pam = pam;
    this.poom = poom;
}

public String getPim() {
    return this.pim;
}

// ...
```

Then:

```
User usr1 = new User("9", "h", "l");
usr1.getPim() // = "9"
// ...
```

Some reading on [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)